# How to check if the file got deleted on AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have the following service method which deletes the file from the AWS S3 bucket. It is returning "true" for a non-exists file on the s3 bucket. I believe it is returning status if the service call is a success but not checking whether the actual file got deleted.
How do I check if the file actually got deleted when I invoke the `deleteObject` on `S3Ojbect`?

**Below is my method code**

```
public boolean deleteS3Object(String multipartKey) {
       
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(multipartKey)) { 
            DeleteObjectRequest deleteObjectRequest = DeleteObjectRequest.builder().bucket("S3Bucket1").key(multipartKey).build();
            DeleteObjectResponse deleteObjectResponse = s3Client.deleteObject(deleteObjectRequest);
            if (deleteObjectResponse != null && deleteObjectResponse.sdkHttpResponse() != null) {
                return deleteObjectResponse.sdkHttpResponse().isSuccessful();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: why do you think file will not be deleted and you must check if the file is deleted? Trust issues?

Comment: I checked the file does not exist, but this method returns "true". My question is how do I check if the file got deleted programmatically using API. If the files do not exist, it must return status either false or some other indicator because it did not delete the file

Comment: First check if the file exists. If it does, delete the file. Wait for few seconds/minutes for eventual consistency to catch up. Check if the file still exists. This will cost you 3 times.

Comment: Your intention of deleting the object implies you do not want that object to exist. If the object did not exist, your intention is fulfilled. That's how _idempotent_ works.

Comment: Ok thanks for the ideas. I am using S3 V2 AWS JDK version and it does not have any direct methods to check if the file exists on S3 and I do not want use getObject because it is expensive as gets the actual file. There is HeadObject but it also have the same issue -    headObjectResponse.sdkHttpResponse().isSuccessful() returns true even if file does not exist. Do you know how to check if an object exists using S3 V2 AWS SDK?

Comment: The `headObject(HeadObjectRequest)` method should throw NoSuchKeyException if the object does not exist. Are you saying that it doesn't?

Comment: Thanks, Jarmod. It worked with headObject(HeadObjectRequest)